# Why does Microsoft Visio copy and paste information from an object in different formats

Tags: excel, ms-office, visio

When I copy and paste multiple lines from a Visio flowchart text box into Excel, the text comes into one cell as wrapped with space seperators (and if there are more than a certain # of lines, stacked cells with this formatting).

When I copy and paste the same information into Word, the text retains it's line breaks.

Why does Excel not see the line breaks and split the information down to the other cells?

If I copy and paste the same information from Word into Excel, it identifies the line breaks and will put the information into seperate cells.

If this is a super user question, I will move, but I was unsure, as am I not really bothered or want a workaround, I would rather understand the reasons for the behavior.

Comment: If this is a programming question, it needs more detail (e.g. how are the line breaks created?). If not, it doesn't belong in stack overflow. For what it's worth, I can't repro the problem you talk about. Multiple line text copied from a shape gets pasted to multiple cells in Excel and multiple lines in Word.  I'm using Office 2013 if that matters.

Comment: If I knew how versions of Office affected this behavior, I would know a better way to describe the issue exactly. How would you suggest I research the information needed for an edit. Line breaks are created using shift+enter.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I get the same behavior when I use shift-enter - it probably isn't version-dependent behavior.  Try just using the enter key to create the line breaks in the shape text.